# nginx: [warn] server name has suspicious symbols with long domain redirect

Tags: server, proxy, nginx, redirect

What is the best way in Nginx to redirect two Long domains URLS, I would like to configure a redirect between two domains like this:

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't find a solution that works.

```
original link:

https://qwerty.test.com/education/7/abc-science

New link

https://www.test.com/education/7/abc-science
```

I have tried this :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name qwerty.test.com/education/7/abc-scienc;
    return 301 $scheme://www.test.com/education/7/abc-science$request_uri;
}
```

Still receive some errors

```
nginx: [warn] server name "education/7/abc-scienc
" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect.conf:9

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

do I need to use this way to redirect form my old URL to new ?

```
location = /content/unique-page-name {
  return 301 /new-name/unique-page-name;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this ? What is wrong here ?

Any help is appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Server name should ONLY be your domain, not your full URL.

Which means your `server_name` should be `qwerty.test.com`.

You then should use location blocks for proper redirects, like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    # Configure your SSL too!
    
    server_name query.test.com;

    location /education/7/abc-science {
        # Unique handler for the URL you want to redirect.
        return 301 $scheme://www.test.com/education/7/abc-science;
    }

    location / {
        # Ideally you need a site level redirect for *any* URI 
        # so that the request is sent to the different site 
        # on any other request URI.
        return 301 $scheme://www.test.com$request_uri;

        # Alternatively, do a different site configuration here for 
        # any other pages that don't redirect.
    }
}
```

Comment: ok , Could you give share some idea , what should be do with two different URL redirect as example i have : SE Engineering Series
https://www.test.com/education/eng  

new 
https://www.test.com/education/engineering or https://www.test.com/research/journal/immunology-infection  

new 
https://www.test.com/research/immunology-and-infection

Comment: Is this like ::  
location /research/journal/immunology-infection {
        # Unique handler for the URL you want to redirect.
        return 301 $scheme://www.test.com/research/immunology-and-infection;
    }

Comment: the curl output  curl -I test.com/research/journal/immunology-infection
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Wed, 19 Oct 2022 19:38:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 134
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://test.com:443/research/journal/immunology-infection

Comment: do I need to add $request_uri in the location block?

Comment: @SantoshBaruah not if you're doing a direct location/url redirect.  You need $request_uri if you're doing a full site redirection from a.site.com to b.site.com at the same request URI.